# Android equivalent of UISwitch

Tags: android, uiswitch

I am looking for android equivalent of UISwitch(iOS), which I could use to switch on/off some functionality. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`ToggleButton`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html), or possibly [`CheckBox`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html) if you prefer.

As of Android 4.0, there is also [`Switch`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html).